# Is it safe to mark a PropertyChangedCallback asynchronous?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a dependency property on a class, let's call it 'SomethingControl':

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomethingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Something", typeof(Something), typeof(SomethingControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(SomethingGotSet));
```

And I have defined the callback method that is being passed into the UIPropertyMetadata constructor as asynchronous:

```
 private async static void SomethingGotSet(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (SomethingControl)d;
        if (control != null)
        {
            control.SomeOtherProperty = await AsynchronousMethodCall();
        }
    }
```

Is this safe to do?  Is this going to cause deadlock or issues on the UI thread?  I've tested it out and it seems to work all right, but I can't find anything in the MSDN documentation using asynchronous property call back methods like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what you are showing us, this looks perfectly safe.

`PropertyChangedCallback` returns nothing (void). The framework would be invoking this as a 'Fire-And-Forget' method.

So, the fact that you're invoking something that may cause a later postback to the user interface thread is fine, and will not directly affect this flow of change notifications.

Deadlocks happen if there are multiple threads, and one thread is waiting for a resource that the other one is holding, and vice versa. There may still be a deadlock somewhere in your system depending upon what `AsynchronousCall` does, but that wouldn't be due to your `SomethingSet` implementation.